# sql server query optimization where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following query

```
declare @pos int=null;
declare @company_code int=null;
declare @category_code int=null;
declare @brand_code int=null;
declare @group_code int=null;
declare @dept_code int=null;
declare @sub_dept_code int=null;
declare @rate_type varchar(20) = null;

select sum(amount),pos as pos_code, mp.Name as pos_name from 

( select POS, (isnull(qty,0) * isnull(mpr.fifo,0)) as amount from 

(
select
a.ICode,a.POS,
isnull(cast((((isnull(sum(a.Qty),0) * mi.Pkg) + 
    ISNULL(sum(a.Loose),0)) / mi.Pkg) as numeric(10,2)),0) as qty

    from t_Stock as a
left join m_Item as mi on a.ICode = mi.SNo

LEFT OUTER JOIN m_Category ON mi.Category = m_Category.SNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN m_Company ON mi.Company = m_Company.SNo 
left join m_PurchRate on mi.SNo = m_PurchRate.itemcode
LEFT JOIN  m_SubDepartment on mi.Department = m_SubDepartment.SNo

where mi.Company = isnull(@company_code,mi.Company)
and mi.Category = isnull(@category_code,mi.Category)
and mi.Brand = isnull(@brand_code,mi.Brand)
and mi.Department = isnull(@sub_dept_code,mi.Department)
and m_Category.num1 = isnull(@group_code,m_Category.num1)
and m_SubDepartment.num1 = isnull(@dept_code,m_SubDepartment.num1)
and a.POS = ISNULL(@pos,a.pos)

group by a.ICode, a.POS,mi.Pkg
) as b 
left join m_PurchRate as mpr on b.ICode = mpr.itemcode) as c 
left join m_POS as mp on mp.SNo = c.POS

group by c.POS,mp.Name
order by pos_name
```

It is a query for calculating inventory stock value for a pos. The problem with this query is WHERE clause. as you can see there are multiple clause in WHERE which is making query very slow.

Indexes on required fields has been created.

How to optimize this query ?

Comment: Where is your query plan?

Comment: sorry, How do i get it ?

Comment: do I post the picture of Query Execution Plan ?

Comment: Add the following statement `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON GO` to your sql query. The results set will be xml which you can post here. We can then recreate the picture here.

Comment: What about DDL of the tables?

Comment: i) are you sure of using left join instead of inner join ?Use inner join where applicable ii)Use SET NOCOUNT ON iii) IS there any uneccessary table use in join .iv)How many records are involve ?
v) Since requirement is not clear so can't comment further.

Comment: @Namphibian SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON wont work as i am declaring variables.